# Encoding issues when displaying non-English text on Rstudio viewer

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, rstudio

I'm using `lda`'s `serVis()` function to display a set of terms analyzed on a large corpus of East Asian characters (simplified Chinese and Japanese), but my `Rstudio` viewer cannot display those text properly (it can only show pure English text), as seen below

[image]

It's clear that this is due to `RStudio`'s encoding issue, so I took someone's suggestion by using the `writeLines()` function to change the default encoding to UTF-8 so as to accommodate some of these foreign texts:

```
writeLines(iconv(readLines("./vis/lda.json"), from = "GBK", to = "UTF-8"), file("./vis/lda.json", encoding="UTF-8"))
```

Note that `serVis()` takes `GBK` as default when processing simplified Chinese text.

I then `reload` the viewer to see if this has any effect on viewer display but nothing changed.

My second try was to click on the `vis` folder automatically created by `serVis`, opening on notepad, and altering its encoding to UTF-8 and, once again, `reload` the viewer, but still nothing changed.

I've read a number of threads on this forum and github, they all pointed to the same solutions as above, but these did not work on my case. It will be very appreciated if anyone could help enlighten me on this.